# Seg. fault when initialising a variable using a method initialised during same initialising list

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list

Why does this gives seg. fault. Clearly it is due to my way of initialising partners_ in C1 , but I am not sure why it is not allowed  like this

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
class C2{
  std::vector<int> partners_;
  public:
  C2(){
   partners_.resize(10); 
   for( auto& n: partners_ ) n = 1;

   } 
   public:
   const std::vector<int>& GetPart( void )const
   {
     return partners_;
   };
};

class C1{

   private:

   const std::vector<int>& partners_;
   const std::unique_ptr<const C2>& C2METHOD;
   public:
   C1(const std::unique_ptr<const C2>& C2METHOD_) : C2METHOD(C2METHOD_), partners_(C2METHOD->GetPart()) { }

};




int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{

   auto TaskDivider = std::make_unique<const C2>(  );
   auto shm     = std::make_unique<C1>( TaskDivider ) ;

};
```

Comment: Should be `partners_(C2METHOD_->GetPart()) `. Data members are initialized in order of their declarations.

Comment: ohh. Okay Thanks!. But just a comment. `C2METHOD` is initialised before, so should it not be available by the time we initialise `partners_`

Comment: As @rafix07 says, the initializers are run in declaration order, not the order in the initializer list.  But consider: It seems both fragile and a premature optimization to set this up.  Note that field `C1::C2METHOD` has a fixed offset in class `C1`, and field `C2::partners_` has a fixed offset in class `C2`.  The compiler should easily discover that, and so there's no advantage performance-wise in the field `C1::partners_` vs. just calling `C2METHOD::GetPart()`.  If that's what you had in mind ...  anyway, IMO, more fragile and co-dependent than necessary for any use case I'm imagining.

Comment: Keeping a reference to a std::unique_ptr is a bit of nonsense.  Either your class owns the pointer, in which case, it should take ownership of the unique_ptr, or  only observes it, in which case, it should be a naked pointer, or shares it, in which case it should be a std::shared_ptr.  The crash occurs because of initilialisation reorderiing done by the compiler.  The member variables are initialized in the order they were declared.

Comment: May I ask why you think it is nonsense? I could use a shared pointer but since I know for this given application the object by the unique pointer will be maintained elsewhere. I tried in fact to google about keeping a reference to an unique pointer and it seemed to me quite valid. Feel free to tell me otherwise